# How can I write a question about profession as a way of life?

Tags: word-choice

I wonder if this statement is sound:

> "Is code your way of life?"

What I am trying to ask here is if coding is the most important thing in someone's life. What is the best way to write that?

Comment: _"Coding is love, coding is life"_ ;)

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for *vocation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask: "Do you [**live and breathe**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+and+breathe) code?"

> to be extremely interested in something
>
> "I found it hard to discuss the poems, since I did not live and
>   breathe poetry like many of my classmates did."

In fact, a Google search of ["live and breathe code"](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%22live+and+breathe+code%22) or ["live and breathe programming"](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%22live+and+breathe+programming%22) or ["live and breathe coding"](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=%22live+and+breathe+coding%22) returns a bunch of results of people using exactly this phrase.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, "Code" is a noun. "Way of life" is generally taken to mean something like a philosophy or code of conduct, so your phrasing seems awkward.

I mean "Is working your way of life" seems less awkward than inserting the noun "Is job your way of life". But even the term working doesn't really fit that phrase.

So, the question then is can "coding" taken to mean an overarching code of conduct? I'm not sure.  I mean, I live a fairly structured life and have already instantiated two child objects with multiple inheritance from their pair of parents.... :P

But I'm not sure I could ever call "coding" my code of conduct, and I don't think I've ever run into anyone who would call something as vague as "coding" as their personal philosophy because it is so nebulous a term with multiple sub-disciplines, frameworks, standards....

On the other hand, you ask someone:

"Is coding your life?" and that would be taken as asking if coding was the predominant interest and activity that this person engages in, and the focus that they wish to continue as that central item.